# Serial communication between NodeMCU and Arduino doesn't work when I try to use the DC jack or Vin

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a unidirectional communication from NodeMCU (ESP8266) -> Arduino UNO. The communication works when I power both the devices to my computer. Note that since it is from NodeMCU to Arduino only, I don't use a voltage regulator. However, when I use a battery supply 9V and connect to DC jack or 9V battery, the serial communication doesn't work. I tried even with the voltage regulator.

It is mentioned that I use something between 9V-12V in the spec. Is it not working because 3.3V/5v from NodeMCU is not sufficient? How do I fix this problem?

1. Currently for the voltage regulator "high", I am supplying 5V from
   Arduino. Should I provide another supply to pass 9v?
2. Does it power on if I provide 5V to DC jack or Vin?

Comment: Please rephrase you question into something understanteble

Answer (score 1):

9V "transistor" (PP3) batteries are very weak. They barely provide enough current to power the Arduino, let alone a power hungry device like an ESP8266.

You're basically trying to tow a caravan with a skateboard.

Comment: What should I use? 9V is sufficient to power arduino for a simple blink program

Comment: AA batteries or Lithium ion.